# Is there any quick previewer for .doc/.docx files?

Tags: software-recommendation, previews

I'd like to know if there's any alternative for previewing these kind of filetypes without having to open LibreOffice. 
I **don't** mean the little thumbnail that appears on Nautilus. I mean a basic, simple viewer, just as *Image Viewer* is to *GIMP Image Editor*.

Answer (score 2):

Gloobus Preview should do the job for you. Just search for it in the Ubuntu Software Centre, you can get all the information about it from [their Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/gloobus-preview)

Comment: Thanks @Victor9098. I've installed it but I don't know how to make it work properly in Nautilus.

Comment: It should work by selecting the file with a single click and then pressing the spacebar. Just make sure you do not have Gnome Sushi installed too. The launchpad page I linked to above should have instructions. When you get the screen to pop-up there should be a gear icon in the corner to access the settings.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Victor9098, except you will also need to install `unoconv` package. This package is necessary for converting office documents so that `gloobus-preview` can preview the files without office suite.
This requirement has been discussed under [this launchpad bug thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gloobus-preview/+bug/625448).

Comment: should they be installed in order? Because I've installed the `gloobus-preview` and I can't see anything changed.

Comment: The `unoconv` worked, although I think that converting the doc to a pdf file just to preview it may not be the smartest thing to do! There must be a better way to do this, but thanks anyway @clearkimura and @victor9098!!!

Answer (score 0):

Right now I am using `gnome-sushi`. You can install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-sushi
```

Then after the installation you are able to get a quick view on the preview of a file. You can access this animation by single-clicking on the file and then pressing the space-bar. Got it from [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/09/gnome-sushi-mac-quick-look-nautilus) if you want an expert to talk about this.

I hope this helps. :D

---

**Update**

Found another tool that allows you to also quickly review `.doc` and `.docx` files. It's called `gloobus-sushi`. To install this feature you have to remove `gnome-sushi`

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-sushi

sudo apt autoremove
```

After you have removed this program you can install `gloobus-sushi` like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gloobus-preview
```

For some types of documents you have to install `unoconv` and `gnumeric`:

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv gnumeric
```

Now you have to install Gloobus Preview helper tool which integrates the application with either Nautilus or Nemo:

- Nautilus:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gloobus-sushi

  nautilus -q
  ```
- Nemo:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install nemo-gloobus-sushi

  nemo -q
  ```

After the installation you are able to preview every file. To use this awesome feature you have to single-click on the file and then press the space-bar.